# Animated ImageView go to Origin back

Tags: android

I want to center an ImageView. I am using this so far:

```
 private void moveViewToScreenCenter(View view, RelativeLayout relativeLayout) {
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int statusBarOffset = dm.heightPixels - relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight();

        int originalPos[] = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen(originalPos);

        int xDest = dm.widthPixels / 2;
        xDest -= (view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2);
        int yDest = dm.heightPixels / 2 - (view.getMeasuredHeight() / 2) - statusBarOffset;

        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, xDest - originalPos[0], 0, yDest - originalPos[1]);
        anim.setDuration(1000);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        view.startAnimation(anim);
    }
```

Now, when the animation ends, the view should go to its origin. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switch this:

> anim.setFillAfter(true);

with this:

> anim.setFillAfter(false);